# Assign output of sql query to a variable in unix

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I am using the following simple UNIX script to assign the output to a variable.

```
count=`sqlplus -s ${DB_USER}/${DB_PASS}@${DB_INST} << END
        SELECT COUNT(column_name) from table_name;
END`

echo $count
```

But I am getting the following error on executing:

```
SP2-0042: unknown command "END" - rest of line ignored.
```

---

count=`sqlplus -s ${DB_USER}/${DB_PASS}@${DB_INST} << END

When I tried to execute the above statement in putty, it was saying as "bad substitution"

So I am using UNIX script to assign the output to a variable.

count=`sqlplus DB_USER/DB_PASS << END
SELECT VERSION_NUMBER from GA_PERIODIC_REFRESH where MODULE_NAME in 'RoaminfoService';
exit;
END`
echo $count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `exit` also:

```
count=`sqlplus -s ${DB_USER}/${DB_PASS}@${DB_INST} <<END
set pages 0 echo off feed off
SELECT COUNT(column_name)
exit;
END`
```